# Localhost me dice 'undefined'

Tags: php, ajax

Este es mi back end, que busca actualizar el nick del usuario

```
<?php

session_start (); 

include_once 'conexion.php';


$respuesta = array();



if( empty($_REQUEST['nick-nuevo']))
{
$respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Nuevo nick, vacio';
}


else

{
$nicknuevo = $_REQUEST['nick-nuevo'];

$sql = 'UPDATE Usuario SET nick = "$nicknuevo" WHERE id = "$_SESSION["id"]"';
mysqli_query ($conn, $sql); 


}
```

Investigando en StackOverflow, me tope con esto [Esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017616/undefined-appearing-in-alert) sin embargo no creo que tenga alguna variable sin definir, trate hacerlo con esto

```
$sql = "UPDATE Usuario SET nick = '". $nicknuevo. "' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']"'";
```

Para ver si cambiaba en algo y me dice el siguente error

> [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' "' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)] que de acuerdo a esto tengo mis quotes malos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565768/php-syntax-error-unexpected-t-constant-encapsed-string pero desde mi perspectiva todo parece estar en orden, no veo ningún error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ANEXO**

```
<?php 

include_once 'header.php'
?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function() {
            $(document).on('click', '#update-btn', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var obj = {  
                    'nick-nuevo': $('#nick-nuevo').val().trim(),  
                };


                $.ajax({
                    url: 'back_update.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: obj,
                    success: function ( respuesta ){
                        alert( respuesta.mensaje );
                    },
                    error: function( e, err, error ){
                    //Añadimos un nodo de error, por si pasa algo en el servidor, esto lo vamos a ver en la consola de depuración
                     console.log(e, err, error);
                    }
                })
            });
        })
</script>


        <div class="main-wrapper"> 

            <form id="update-form" class="signup-form" method="POST"> 
            <h2>Actualizar</h2>


                <input id="nick-nuevo"type="text" name="nick_nuevo" placeholder="nick nuevo" required> </input>


            <button id="update-btn"type="submit" name="submit" value="actualizar"> 
            Actualizar
            </button>


            </form>
<?php 

include_once'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema?

Comment: No logro hacer el update en la base de dato

Comment: Has un var_dump($_POST) envíame lo que te trae el formulario.

Comment: array(1) { ["nick-nuevo"]=> string(3) "fer" } @Oswuell

Comment: ¿Estás trabajando con Ajax? ¿Cuál es el código que maneja la respuesta del servidor? Por cierto realmente no respondes nada desde el servidor, al menos en el código que muestras.

Comment: @A.Cedano Efectivamente, trabajo con Ajax, edite el post principal agregando mi script de Ajax y agregando la etiqueta a la pregunta. Por cierto que entendemos por " Por cierto realmente no respondes nada desde el servidor" ? Soy nuevo y este tipo de cosas que pueden parecer obvias se me escapan.

Comment: has un console.log() o alert() a toda la variable `respuesta` del ajax y pega lo que te regresa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que ya eres mi padawan. 
Tienes unos cuantos errores en tu código y se puede perfeccionar un poco, te explico:

```
<?php

session_start (); 
include_once 'conexion.php';
$respuesta = array();

if( empty($_REQUEST['nick-nuevo'])){
$respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Nuevo nick, vacio';
}


else{
  $nicknuevo = $_REQUEST['nick-nuevo'];

  //Tu tienes esto
  $sql = "UPDATE Usuario SET nick = '". $nicknuevo. "' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']"'";

  //Se te olvido concatenar la última parte con un " . ", así debería quedar
  $sql = "UPDATE Usuario SET nick = '". $nicknuevo. "' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id'] . "'";
  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);    

  //Puedes comprobar la actualización del campo así
  if( mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0){
    $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Se actualizó correctamente el registro';
  }

  else{
    $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'No fue posible actualizar el registro';
  }
}

//Se te está pasando regresar $respuesta en formato JSON y su encabezado
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $respuesta );
?>
```

Así te debería de funcionar

Saludos

Comment: Justo iba a escribir una respuesta parecida a la tuya, pero basada en consultas preparadas para dar seguridad al código, el cual como está ahora es altamente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Además el código tiene que ser real, no puedes decir que se actualizó un registro sin verificarlo con alguna función del tipo `affected_rows`.

Comment: Si, va aprendiendo, atosigarlo con información creo que lo puede perder, no estará de más hacerle su conocimiento que existe. Además creo que su variable de sesión está expirando. Anteriormente ya había abierto este developer un hilo con problemas en su desarrollo, y bueno sugerí la prevención de SQL por que no tenía hasheado nada en los passwords, pero creo que va bien, poco a poco.

Comment: Hahaha algo así, si. Efectivamente funcionó, y lanzar el mensaje al final, para decir que se actualizó o no el registro, evita que aparezca el mensaje "undefined".   Por cierto, he estado investigando, sobre el [header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $respuesta );] y me sigue sin quedar claro que labor cumplen en todo este codigo, lei que puedo verlo en network-> header https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284986/the-usage-of-headercontent-typeapplication-json  y si esta allí, pero que problemas ocasiona su ausencia, por que es necesitado? Gracias por la ayuda !

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto

```
    <?php

session_start (); 

include_once 'conexion.php';

$respuesta = array();

if( empty($_REQUEST['nick-nuevo']))
{
    $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Nuevo nick, vacio';

}else{

    $nicknuevo = $_REQUEST['nick-nuevo'];
    $id = $_SESSION["id"];

    $sql = "UPDATE Usuario SET nick = '".$nicknuevo."' WHERE id = ".$id;

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

     if(!$result)
     { 
        $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Error al actualizar';

     } else{ 

        $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Actualizado con exito';
    } 

}

?>
```

Comment: Efectivamente logró actual, pero el localhost me seguia diciendo undefined al momento de enviar el submit, gracias por la ayuda Oswuell.